# How to get info from an object with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I need to get the filename info from two files sended with multer, but when I try to send a JSON with the response, it sends a Object: null prototype and the info from the images. But I can´t access to it. What can I do?
Here is my code:

```
// Multer File
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, "../../imagesDirectory"));
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null,
      `${req.params.campana}-${req.params.metodo}-${file.fieldname}-${new Date()
        .toISOString()
        .replace(/:/g, "-")}-${file.originalname}`
    );
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const uploads = upload.fields([
  { name: "image1" },
  { name: "image2" },
  { name: "image3" },
  { name: "image4" },
  { name: "image5" },
  { name: "image6" },
  { name: "image7" },
]);

module.exports = uploads;
```

```
// Controller
const uploadFile = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.files) {
    console.log("You need to add an image");
    res.json({ err: "You need to add an image" });
  } else {
    console.log(req.files);

    let name = req.files.filename;
    res.json({ msg: "Image Upload", rows: name });
  }
};

module.exports = { uploadFile };
```